# UnfoldingMaps doesn't refresh in JPanel

Tags: java, swing, processing

For a application I'm developing, I make use of the UnfoldingMaps library for displaying a map. The map is placed inside a JPanel. In the same JPanel other Jpanels are showed.
So I change between the map and other panels with the help of buttons.

The problem is that the map doesn't refresh. I can display it once and when I've displayed another Panel, and go back to the map, the map won't display. The only option I got then is to restart the application.

```
    private void showVis(String chart) {
    //visual is the JPanel where elements are viewed in
    visual.removeAll();

    if (chart.equals("bar")) {

        bar.setPart("", partial, location);
        bar.createVisualisation(ai);
        if (bar.checkGraph()) {
            System.out.println("Really creating bar");
            ChartPanel panB = bar.getPanel();
            JPopupMenu popB = panB.getPopupMenu();
            panB.setPopupMenu(popB);
            visual.add(panB);
            visual.validate();

        }
         } else if (chart.equals("map")) {
        map = null;
        map = new Maps();
        map.setPart("", partial, location);
        map.createVisualisation(ai);

        if (map.checkGraph()) {
            map.init();
            visual.add(map);

            visual.validate();
        }
    }
```

the string chart decides which panel will be showed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> In the same JPanel other Jpanels are showed. So I change between the
>   map and other panels with the help of buttons.

- it should be `parentPanel.revalidate();` and then `parentPanel.repaint();`
- better is usage of [CardLayout (So I change between the
  map and other panels with the help of buttons.)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html) is designated for this purpose, rather than to remove and then add a new `JComponent`(s) to already visible Swing GUI

Comment: I've tried your solution with the CardLayout and this worked. Thanks a lot